# Segmented control without reloading

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uiviewanimation

I'm using a segmented control to switch between two different views. 
However, with my code, the views reload every time they are showed.

Here's my code:

```
        let newController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerIdentifiers[sender.selectedSegmentIndex]) as! userProfileViewController
        let oldController = childViewControllers.last as! UIViewController

        newController.userToShow = self.userToShow

        oldController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        addChildViewController(newController)
        newController.view.frame = oldController.view.frame


        transitionFromViewController(oldController, toViewController: newController, duration: 0.25, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations:{ () -> Void in
            // nothing needed here



            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in

                oldController.removeFromParentViewController()

                newController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)



        })

    } else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {


        let newController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewControllerIdentifiers[sender.selectedSegmentIndex]) as! secondProfilePageViewController
        let oldController = childViewControllers.last as! UIViewController

        newController.userToShow = self.userToShow

        oldController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        addChildViewController(newController)
        newController.view.frame = oldController.view.frame



        transitionFromViewController(oldController, toViewController: newController, duration: 0.25, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations:{ () -> Void in
            // nothing needed here

            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                oldController.removeFromParentViewController()

                newController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        })
    }

}
```

I've also tried to do this by using two UIContainerViews, and hiding the one I didn't need, but that way I couldn't have any animation in the passage between the views.

To better understand, I would like to do something like the Today/Notifications stuff in every Iphone.

Answer (score 2):

You are wondering why the view controllers are reloaded when you switch. The reason is because you are calling `instantiateViewController...` which, well, instantiates a **new** view controller.

Instead, have a container view controller with the two container views and *keep references* of the two controllers (as variables) in this container controller.

Comment: But how can I animate the passage, instead of hiding the view that I don't need?

Comment: I thought the problem was that you always get a new view, not that it is not animating.

Comment: @dpstart you are already using the container view controller like he mentioned, it is the VC running your animation code. You just need to store references to your two VCs you want to swap between on that VC. I would create the two VCs in your viewDidLoad and just keep track of which one is visible. Your instantiate line is literally creating a new VC, so you need to only use it one time per VC you want to swap between.

Comment: I now instantiate the VCs in ViewDidLoad(), but the app crashes as I get to the view with the container... @DougWatkins

Comment: Amend your question to include the crash details, otherwise nobody will be able to help you.